# Why There Is Error showing "File Not Found" on my Django about webpage even after putting txt file in codebase?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Here Is My about File code

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def readfile(request):
    openit = open("hell.txt", 'r')
    hhhhh = openit.read()
    return HttpResponse(hhhhh)
```

Here Is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import about

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('about/', about.readfile, name="readfile"),
]
```

Here Is My hell.txt file in same directory

```
vdsseebelouvbuobewoubouerbrobgerubrobogougbeoebergbrobeobwebewbvdsseebelouvbuobewoubouer
```

Comment: What is the project structure and where is `hell.txt` located in this?

Comment: What is the current working directory?

Comment: hell.txt Located In The Same Directory in which about file is...

Comment: _Here Is My hell.txt file in same directory_ It doesn't matter that it's in the same directory as the program file.  The program is looking in the _current directory_, which is not the same.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: You could use a full pathname for the open() call: `open('/some/full/directory/hello.txt')`

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: @JohnGordon not working by changing path

Comment: If it's not working, then the pathname must be wrong.  Make sure it is correct.

Comment: @JohnGordon tried changing path but not working as well

Comment: @Sayse same hell.txt is located in which urls.py and about.py is located

Comment: Side note: use a context manager, as right now if you do manage to open the file you're never closing it ...

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you havent set up 'static files' which is Djangos way of dealing with external resources ([official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)).
In order to serve thosoe files the project config needs to be adapted(see link). After that, adding the newly configured directory to your urls.py should do the trick.

But watch out! Depending on your branch (developenemt vs production) the method may differ. But everything you need should be explained in the linked article.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # some paths
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

On the bottom of the page follow the link 'How to deploy static files' after the setup, deploy your files cleanly to the project.

Comment: That won't help with this. It's not a static file being served, it's a file being read in with `open`. for that, they need the correct path, as others have stated.

Comment: It is recommended to access them with the STATIC_DIR to not expose directory-structure to users when serving files.

Comment: They're not serving a file though - they're reading it and serving the contents. Nothing in that would expose the directory structure.